# Why compiler time increase with this template?

Tags: c++, templates, mingw-w64

Here's a part of code I'm compiling from my `Plugin.cpp`:

```
...
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleButton>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::RESET_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSwitch>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::RUN_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleKnob>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SEED_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleKnob>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CLOCK_SWING_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleKnob>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CLOCK_RANDOM_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleKnob>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CLOCK_OFFSET_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleKnob>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CLOCK_CURVE_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SECTION_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SECTION_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SECTION_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_2_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_2_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_3_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_3_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_3_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_4_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_4_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_4_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SECTION_4_STEP_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_2_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_2_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_3_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_3_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_3_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_4_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_4_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_4_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SECTION_4_STEP_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_2_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_2_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_3_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_3_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_3_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_4_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_4_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_4_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SECTION_4_STEP_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_2_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_2_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_3_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_3_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_3_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_4_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_4_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_4_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SECTION_4_STEP_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_SERIAL_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_SERIAL_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_SERIAL_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_SERIAL_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_1_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_5_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_6_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_7_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_8_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_9_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_10_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_11_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_12_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_13_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_14_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_15_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::SERIAL_STEP_16_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_DIV_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_DIV_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_DIV_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_DIV_2ND_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_DIV_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_DIV_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_DIV_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_DIV_2ND_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_DIV_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_DIV_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_DIV_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_DIV_2ND_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_DIV_2_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_DIV_3_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_DIV_4_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_DIV_2ND_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_LENGTH_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_LENGTH_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_LENGTH_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_LENGTH_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_LENGTH_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_LENGTH_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_LENGTH_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_LENGTH_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_VELOCITY_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_VELOCITY_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH1_VELOCITY_DIV_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_VELOCITY_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_VELOCITY_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH2_VELOCITY_DIV_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_VELOCITY_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_VELOCITY_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH3_VELOCITY_DIV_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_VELOCITY_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_VELOCITY_VAR_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
addParam(MyModuleWidget::create<MyModuleSlider>(Vec(10, 10), module, this, ParamEnum::CH4_VELOCITY_DIV_PARAM, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5));
...
```

On another `MyModuleWidget.cpp` file, if I write this `*create` function, it tooks somethings like 2-3 seconds to compile both files:

```
struct MyModuleWidget {
    //...

    template <class T = MyModuleWidget>
    static T* create(Vec pos, MyModuleModule *MyModuleModule, MyModuleModuleWidget *MyModuleModuleWidget, int paramId, float minValue, float maxValue, float defaultValue) {
        T *widget = ParamWidget::create<T>(pos, MyModuleModule, paramId, minValue, maxValue, defaultValue);

        return widget;
    }
};
```

BUT, if I use this instead (note one line of code added):

```
struct MyModuleWidget {
    //...

    template <class T = MyModuleWidget>
    static T* create(Vec pos, MyModuleModule *MyModuleModule, MyModuleModuleWidget *MyModuleModuleWidget, int paramId, float minValue, float maxValue, float defaultValue) {
        T *widget = ParamWidget::create<T>(pos, MyModuleModule, paramId, minValue, maxValue, defaultValue);

        widget->nwkModule = nwkModule; // added line

        return widget;
    }
};
```

it tooks somethings like 10 (or more) seconds to compile the file `Plugin.cpp`.

What's going on? Why compiling time is larger with that line?

**Note:** here's addParam function, if needed:

```
void ModuleWidget::addParam(ParamWidget *param) {
    params.push_back(param);
    addChild(param);
}
```

**Note2:** I've noticed that it becomes "slow" if I use 3 different `T` when compiling `Plugin.cpp`. For example: if I only `addParam` types `MyModuleKnob` and `MyModuleSlider`, its fast. If later I also add the type `MyModuleButton` on those `addParam`, it becomes slow.